# Why won't my different cubic-bezier timings work

Tags: css, bezier, keyframe

Seem to be having a problem where the bezier numbers I put in are not actually having different effects on the rotation of an element. I will be rotating all 4 of these dots at different speeds over the same duration...stuck at even getting 2 to behave differently:

```
<div id="dotcontainer1" class="dotcont">
    <div id="dot1" class="dot"></div>
</div>

<div id="dotcontainer2" class="dotcont">
    <div id="dot2" class="dot"></div>
</div>

<div id="dotcontainer3" class="dotcont">
    <div id="dot3" class="dot"></div>
</div>

<div id="dotcontainer4" class="dotcont">
    <div id="dot4" class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Styled like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #414a5b;
}

.dotcont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.dot {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#dot1 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#dot2 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#dot3 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#dot4 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.25;
}

#dotcontainer1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (0,0,0.58,1);   
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#dotcontainer2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (.42,0,1,1);    
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Here is a link to the pen: http://codepen.io/chris86/pen/jWqGvM?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjKmxR?editors=110

In order to create that effect I've used the following site that allows you to create whatever cubic-bezier you want:http://cubic-bezier.com/

The one I've used are:

```
cubic-bezier(.2,.78,.69,.86);
cubic-bezier(.95,.1,1,.85);
```

Comment: I see, think the problem was that I didn't have a space after the word bezier right? seems to work on my pen when I remove that

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the animation duration

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #414a5b;
}

.dotcont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.dot {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#dot1 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#dot2 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#dot3 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#dot4 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.25;
}

#dotcontainer1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (0,0,0.58,1);   
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#dotcontainer2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (.42,0,1,1);    
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#dotcontainer3 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin3;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (0,0,0.58,1);   
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin3 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#dotcontainer4 {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin4;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier (.42,0,1,1);    
}   

@-webkit-keyframes spin4 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: thanks, actually think it was because a space was missing, I need the duration to remain the same actually, just get from start to finish moving at different speeds throughout :)